# Unable to get the Latest files from TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs, tfsbuild

First i tried to get the latest files from the TFS , but shows a dialog box stating that i have all the latest files.
Then i tried to getting the latest through Get Specific Version, still i was unable to get the latest files.

I even tried deleting the workspace.

Comment: Have you mapped the server path to a local path?

Comment: yes , i have mapped the server path to my local folder

Comment: can you successfully download the files to a different computer? can anyone else get the files to theirs?

Comment: well, yes some of my team members are able to download the files.

Answer (score 0):

The [Team Foundation Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980963.aspx) include a command called Scorch that may be of use. The intent of the command is to ensure your local folders/files match exactly with the server folders/files. I'd be sure that you don't have anything in your local folders that isn't under source control that you don't want to lose before using this command or have a good backup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're going through the GetLatest from a Solution/Project in Solution Explorer, but I've found that to not work -- not often -- but every once in awhile.

When that happens, I normally have better luck doing a GetLatest against the folder/project in Team Explorer's Source Control Explorer.  I haven't yet had a Get Latest issue that needed anything more drastic...

(knock on wood)

Answer (score 0):

One of my co-workers just had this problem. We fixed this by right-clicking the root node in Source Control Explorer, going to `Advanced`, then `Map to Local Folder` and applying a local mapping recursively ensuring that we wiped out any existing mappings when prompted.